# Delete file version history in SharePoint more than one month old

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the easiest way to delete file version history in SharePoint online that are more than one month old?

Is there some software that can achieve this? I know of [DMS-Shuttle](https://dms-shuttle.com/documentation/delete-version-history-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/) but that only allow you to specify how many versions to keep, not a date.

Comment: This PowerShell script might be applicable: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-online-delete-version-history-using-powershell.html